# some questions about wso2 api manager performance

Tags: performance, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I follow the document 《wso2-whitepaper-wso2-and-api-management-a-technical-evaluation-guide.pdf》 test wso2 api management performance. As The article said,the
wso2am system able to handle more than 8,000 API calls per secondCan be achieved? But I get the test results of only 1000cps. I want to know,the result 8000,does it open the gateway key cache?or dose it have done other methods to improve the performance?And during we test the wso2 api manager performance,we find the key manager is  Large proportion of performance?And last,could you tell me how to improve the wso2 api manager performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2:1  proportion for keymanager:gateway. key manger has to validate keys, so it requires more processing power. And also we recommend to go with [distribution](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Distributed+Deployment) setup

Please find tuning parameters [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Distributed+Deployment)http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Performance+Tuning+Recommendations

Comment: it seems don not improvent.as I set Set the following in /repository/conf/nhttp.properties file:

http.socket.timeout=60000
snd_t_core=400
snd_t_max=500
snd_io_threads=32 
lst_t_core=400
lst_t_max=500
lst_io_threads=32 
the performance is Worse，I also one question：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673219/wso2am-gateway-how-to-full-use-of-cpu

Comment: We don't have any published performance numbers..But some recent testings shows that AM can handle ~=2500 TPS with around 700/800 concurrent users with  amazon xlarge instance..But it depends on your hardware, backend service response time..

Comment: ok,thanks.I direct call api server without am,the cps is 14000.And with wso2 api manager the cps is 5.6k with enable the gateway key cache.I think it is not the server or hardware problem.

Comment: and I find wso2am have pubilished the performance number,please look :http://wso2.com/download/wso2-whitepaper-wso2-and-api-management-a-technical-evaluation-guide.pdf-----the last Chapter--performance:Chapter

Comment: this the article said:Performance
We have done extensive performance testing both at customer sites and in our performance lab in 
Colombo. 
For our testing, we used a small deployment of two machines (each with Core i5 @ 3.1Ghz, 8Gb memory, 
RHEL Server 5.8): one server as the key server, one as the gateway. With this configuration, we see the 
system able to handle more than 8,000 API calls per second. This was with zero dropped messages. We also 
observed an additional average latency of 6ms compared to going direct without OAuth2 key validation.